# javascript location object in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, location, icefaces

Why is it that I can't load a new page with the `window.location` object in javascript when the code is called from a icefaces commandButton onclick event? My js code:

```
function newPage(){
    location = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

It works fine when I call it from a html element, but not an icefaces component (and probably jsf).

Just testing with google, but when this line executes, it just reloads the current page and appends `?rvn=8` or `?rvn=4` at the end of the url.. it does not load google.com. Can someone explain why?

`window.open("http://www.google.com", "google");` works, but opens in a different window, which is not what I want. I need it in the current window.

Thank You

my button:

```
<ice:commandButton actionListener="#{easp$PartsInv.deleteRecord}" id="deleteBtn" value="Delete" partialSubmit="true" onclick="newPage();">
     <f:attribute name="curRec" value="#{currentRow}" />
 </ice:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function newPage(){
    location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function newPage(){
    top.window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: damn, that didn't do it either

Comment: What else would you like? I pretty much gave all the info. I added my button tag tho

Comment: top.windows.locatoin must work, you could debug your js code by firebug or chrome developer tool.

Comment: it doesn't work >< and i dont think firebug would help in this situation